# "Frontend Instance Hours" quota

Tags: google-app-engine

I registered a new application that uses Google App engine and faced with a problem. Even though "Frontend Instance Hours" quota is 28 hours I constantly face with a problem that it reaches it's limit even when I do not constantly use the server to send requests. Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Another problem is that even though I received 300$ for free that I can spend during the free trial I can't use them because every time I go to App Engine->Settings and set "Daily budget" to any number I always receive "An error occurred. Some settings may not have been updated successfully" message and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Does anybody have any idea why I see this error?

Comment: It's hard to give an answer without seeing any code and what it actually does. Also, your second question is off topic. Please read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide first and try to improve your question, otherwise the chances of getting an answer you are looking for are fairly low.

Comment: check the number of instances you have deployed. it will spin more up as load increases. You can fix it to 1 instance with "manual scaling" and then it will only use 24 hours in 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

On the first questions: limit the number or instances running

If you run 2 F1 instances, they will spend free quota in 14 hours.
If you run 1 F2 instance, it will also spend free quota in 14 hours.

See more here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/

On the second questions:

I got the same error during the free trial. When I enabled billing,
the error went away. So the free trial is just a sales gimmick.